# XPages ViewPanel Empty Start and End Rows

Tags: xpages

I am using a simple ViewPanel to display a View on an XPage.
Further I am trying to hide to start and end row which are empty.
I am using Bootstrap3 as application theme.
Is there a way to remove the empty start and end rows ? I also tried a theme but thats not working as well. Some help would be very appreciated.

[image: Empty Rows]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Johnny,

ViewPanel rendered html code is not really "nice", and I'm quite sure you cannot delete them...

But you can hide them. Go into the "All properties" section of the view panel and add a CSS class in the viewStyleClass parameter (last one of the styling section).

Then in your css add the following rule:

table.viewClass > tbody > tr:first-child, table.viewClass > tbody > tr:last-child {
  display: none;
}

In this example I added the class "viewClass" in the viewStyleClass parameter

Comment: great, and put this in a CCS class and reference it in your theme for the table and your done for all viewPanels